# UIImage save to document directory with Low memory usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

I save the `UIImage` to Library directory,but this takes more memory to save the image I write this code to save the Image.

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i<[_selectedAssetArray count]; i++)
{
    NSError *error;
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
                                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/VideoMaker"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsDirectory])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
        UIImage *image=[_selectedAssetArray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);
        [imageData writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Di%d.%@",i, @"png"]] atomically:YES];
}i++;
```

In this code *_selectedAssetArray* is my `UIImage` Array that contains more than 50 or100 images.
When I save the Images the memory increase from 20 MB to 200 or more.So that My app Terminate due to the Pressure of Memory...

Comment: You can check this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324990/how-to-save-nsmutable-array-image-into-plist-or-document-folder-multiple-images

Answer (score 0):

This might be worth a try, put it in a LOW queue, or even try replacing `LOW` by `BACKGROUND`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0ul), ^{

    // Your code here
       [self saveData:1]
});
```

EDIT: Let's say all your photos are saved in photoArray, which is an NSMutableArray.

Note, this requires some indentation, i've type that from scratch on SO. Also, this is very very ugly, so if it works, you need to tweak it at little (for example, at least use a switch for the proceed, and maybe split into methods that make this more readable)

```
 - (void)saveData:(int)proceed
{
   if (proceed == 1){
      if([photoArray count] >= 10){
           (for int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){

           // I'm making up the code but you'll know what i mean
           // I'm saving the last photo (or the first one, it doesn't matter)
           // of the array of pictures

             [self savePhoto:[photoArray lastObject]];

          // now your photo has ben saved, 
         //  we can remove if from the array so the loop doesn't do it twice

            [photoArray removeObject:[photoArray lastObject]];
        }
         // Here you check if you have to start over, or just do the last photos.
         if ([photoArray count] >= 10){
             [self saveData:1];
             }
         if ([photoArray count] < 10 && [photoArray count] >0){
             [self saveData:2];
             }
         if ([photoArray count] == 10){
             break;
             }
      }
    }
     if (proceed == 2)

      if([photoArray count] < 10 && [photoArray count] > 0){
           (for int i = 0 ; i < [photoArray count]; i++){
            // I'm making up the code but you'll know what i mean
           // I'm saving the last photo (or the first one, it doesn't matter)
           // of the array of pictures

             [self savePhoto:[photoArray lastObject]];

          // now your photo has ben saved, 
         //  we can remove if from the array so the loop doesn't do it twice

            [photoArray removeObject:[photoArray lastObject]];
            }
```

Comment: It doesn't work ...Any other idea for this ..? please help me

Comment: Ok then what you should do is (while still using the background queue) use a method that does, say, 10 picture at a time, and calls itself again when the 10th picture has been processed. This might help with the memory peaks.

Comment: I want save Image to Library for later use.I am creating VideoMaker app.

Comment: Still, try and save them "slowly" (10 by 10 for example). I'll edit my asnwer quickly

Comment: Try what I edited. It should ( if it compiles ) treat your stuff slowly. You need to adapt the code because it's just an example though

Comment: Did you check turning your save to atomically:NO?